# how to show output of day using hours in react.js

Tags: reactjs

```
how to show 12:00:00 and 10:23:33 
 show output of duration of Days or hours
```

using this startTime and endTime i want out-put of a day or hours without any library

```
const subject = () => {
    const StarTimes = 12:00:00
    const endites = 10:23:33 
return(
<></>
)
}
```

Comment: Can you explain clearly what is your requirement?. According to my understanding you the difference between start TIme and end Time in hours. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

To output difference in e.g. days natively, you can use Intl.DateTimeFormat
:

```
const formatter = new Intl.RelativeTimeFormat("en");
const diff = new Date(endTime) - new Date(starTime);

const diffFormated = formatter.format(-diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24), "days");
```